# Firebug Css debugger and asset generated file

Tags: css, debugging, firebug

I have this little problem. I am trying to fix the style of a website by examining the css using Firebug (in firefox).

The thing is that i can't figure out where this specific style is at because it appears in some

8EdeWkQAAAA%3d%3d">http://localhost:19478/asset.axd?id=kQAAAB-LCAAAAAAABADsvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1StfgdKEIgGATJNiQQBDswYjN5pLsHWlHIymrKoHKZVZlXWYWQMztnbz33nvvvffee--997o7nU4n99__P1xmZAFs9s5K2smeIYCqyB8_fnwfPyJ-8Uezjx597xd_tPro0Ucn1bLNl-1Ho4_O-bMlfdbmZV4Xb8fTarGoluNp09DX1UePdn7JKGywyNu6ct_v_pLv_5Lvjz6attzkXXtXvrmkP_d2dvfGe-NPdx7QB1Pq_t6n9-mXjx619Tr_Jf9PAAAA_8EdeWkQAAAA%3d%3d

Obviously this seems to me something that is being created by the DOM?

I am attaching an image. Take a look at it and you will get a better picture of what i am asking here.

Thanks

[Here is the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4pfhm3uhwraw5g/SummaryScreenShot.png)

Comment: I think that the styles are specified into the page, not in an external css file, so FireBug shows these string.

Comment: Your answer helped me. It wasn't actually into the page, but it seems like Telerik has a RegistrarScript or something like that. So, when i read your answer that turned on the light bulb :). I went into the two css files Telerik automatically registers and i found my problem there. Thank you.